# LoadLibrary does not reuse loaded library

Tags: c, windows, dll, loadlibrary

My directory structure is as follows:

```
test
  dir
    a.dll  <-- version 1
  a.dll    <-- version 2
  myapp.exe
```

I expect that by themselves, `LoadLibrary("dir\\a.dll")` will use version 1 and `LoadLibrary("a.dll")` will use version 2, while together:

```
LoadLibrary("dir\\a.dll");
LoadLibrary("a.dll");
```

Both will refer to version 1, according to [the documentation of `LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However, when I try to do that in the application I'm working on, **line 1 loads version 1 and line 2 loads version 2.**

I've tried to write a small reproducer but in the reproducer it works as expected - so there's something that breaks that in the larger application or in the loaded dll. **What can cause that, and how can I solve it?**

And to emphasize, the two loads are adjacent in the larger application, there are no system calls between line 1 and 2 (and it's of course the same process). I originally did want to put a lot of code between them, but saw this issue and reproduced it even when they are adjacent.

I've also tried with the following directory structure:

```
test
  dir
    a.dll  <-- version 1
  myapp.exe
Windows
  System32
    a.dll  <-- version 2
```

But again, line 1 loads version 1 and line 2 loads version 2.

Comment: Explain how you *know* that the DLL gets loaded again.  And don't obfuscate the **most** important info, the name of the file.

Comment: @HansPassant I use `GetModuleFileName` on the returned handle to verify the actual path of the loaded dll. Also when running a function from the dll I see it comes from version 2 according to its behavior. And what do you mean by the name of the file? Is the name of the dll meaningful? I thought having the same name is the only thing that matters here?

Comment: @HansPassant [here's a link to the complete reproducer code](http://pastebin.com/3iE5qAXp) (which works as expected). The code in the large application is nearly identical, except running from inside a method and not from `main`. It's C++ and not C, but as far as I understand it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: GetModuleFileName does not tell you that a DLL is loaded twice.  The debugger's module list does.

Comment: What do you mean by "the complete reproducer code (which works as expected)"?  Does it reproduce the problem, or does it work as expected?

Comment: @HarryJohnston it loads the same dll, so it works as expected and does not reproduce my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. In fact, it only requires some thought - the answer is obvious in retrospect: such a situation can occur when the dll was already loaded before my first `LoadLibrary` call. So the 1st call, with the explicit path, loads version 1 - while the 2nd call, without a path, defaults to the *first* loaded dll (according to the documentation), which happens to be version 2.

This can be fixed by forcefully unloading the library before the first `LoadLibrary` call:

```
HMODULE alreadyLoaded = GetModuleHandle("a.dll");
if (alreadyLoaded) {
    FreeLibrary(alreadyLoaded);
}
```

Although that was enough for me, a more complete solution is to do so in a loop, to handle cases where the dll was loaded multiple times before:

```
HMODULE alreadyLoaded = GetModuleHandle("a.dll");
while (alreadyLoaded) {
    FreeLibrary(alreadyLoaded);
    alreadyLoaded = GetModuleHandle("a.dll");
}
```

Of course, this is potentially dangerous - especially if the original `HMODULE` was stored somewhere, as this renders it invalid.

Comment: This is liable to break whatever code loaded the library in the first place.

Comment: ... instead, consider using an explicit path in both calls, e.g., `LoadLibrary(".\\a.dll")`